# Application always return a login page on unauthorized controller or action instead of 401

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, openiddict

When i am trying to send some API request without the access token it always return a response to a login page. I have the implementation of `implicit-flow` and `client-credentials`.

How can i implement the un-authorized (error, 401) message when accessing a API without redirecting to a login page. But, when there is request for login with the `implicit-flow` then only the server should redirects to the login page

```
services.AddOpenIddict().AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<AWSContext>()
               .ReplaceDefaultEntities<Guid>();

    }).AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.UseMvc();
        options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/authorize")
                 .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
                 .EnableLogoutEndpoint("/connect/logout")
                 .EnableIntrospectionEndpoint("/connect/introspect")
                 .EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/api/userinfo");
        options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

        options.RegisterScopes(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                               OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                               OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);


        options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();

        options.AllowImplicitFlow();
        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
        //options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
        options.UseJsonWebTokens();
    });//.AddValidation();

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme })
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();

    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
});

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration["SettingsConfig:AuthUrl"];
    options.Audience = "resource-server-1";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
        RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role
    };
});
```

Example:

```
[Route("api/location")]
[Authorize]
public class LocationController : Controller
{
    [Route("get/{Id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetLocation(long Id)
    {
        var location = _locationService.GetLocationById(Id);
        return Ok(location);
    }
}
```

Now, here when i am trying to make the API call without the access token, the application is returning login page as a response. How could i configure my application to not return a Login page, instead return some custom error code? without effecting the `implicit-flow`

[image: API returning login page when accessing API without access token]

Comment: Use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` instead of just `[Authorize]`, that will use the default authentication scheme, that is the cookie handler used by ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: i tried `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` but got the same login page error. isn't there any way to configure to send the custom error message from the api?

Comment: Try to remove your global authorization policy first.

Comment: Instead of redirecting to the login page from the `spa page application` the application got redirected to `HTTP ERROR 401` error page. and only when i remove `options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` the SPA return to login page. Should i remove that?